# Не отображается разметка для горизонтального положения экрана

Tags: android, android-bundle, orientation

Имеется код следующей активности:

```
package asus.example.com.exercise3;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class ActorDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String uri;
    private String sInformation;
    private ImageView avatar;
    private TextView information;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_actor_detail_land);
        }
        else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_actor_detail);
        }
        avatar = findViewById(R.id.big_avatar);
        information = findViewById(R.id.information);
        int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0);

        if (savedInstanceState==null) {
            uri = DataUtil.generateActors().get(position).getLargeImage().toString();
            sInformation = DataUtil.generateActors().get(position).getDescription();
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Uri.parse(uri)).into(avatar);
            information.setText(sInformation);
        }
        else {
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("Uri"))).into(avatar);
            information.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("Information"));

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_actor_detail_land);
        }
        else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_actor_detail);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
        bundle.putString("Uri", uri);
        bundle.putString("Information", sInformation);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle bundle){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle);

    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что когда поворачиваю устройство - вместо макета появляется просто белый экран. Как я понимаю, проблема в том, что когда поворачивается устройство пересоздается активность и теряются данные. Но ведь я их добавляю в `Bundle` и потом из него вытягиваю. Однако когда смотрю по дебаггеру - сюда

```
else {
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("Uri"))).into(avatar);
                information.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("Information"));

            }
```

даже не заходит. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Активность не пересоздаётся - Вы ведь взяли на себя обязательство обрабатывать поворот экрана когда добавили атрибут `android:configChanges="orientation"` в манифест.
В методе `onConfigurationChanged` Вы меняете макет и всё - не находя новые экземпляры вью и не заполняя их данными.
Вынесите инициализацию в отдельный метод и вызывайте его и в `onCreate`, и в `onConfigurationChanged`.

P.S. Непонятно зачем Вы вручную воспроизводите стандартное поведение активности при повороте. Если убрать атрибут из манифеста и положить в папки `layout` и `layout-land` соответствующие файлы разметки с **одинаковым** названием, то система сама пересоздаст активити и по тому же `id` вернёт "правильный" ресурс макета.